# Человек, празднующий день рождения! Синонимы

Tags: синонимы

Какие синонимы есть для обозначения человека, отмечающего день рождения?
 Я нашла следующие: виновник торжества, именинник (хотя спорно, именины редко совпадают с днем рождения, хотя сейчас это слово, мне кажется, уже отдаляется от собственно именин), новорожденный (в переносном значении, разг.) , юбиляр (но это только при условии "круглых" дат)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для обозначения человека, празднующего день рождения, существовало слово "рожденник".
В современном языке допустимо использовать "именинник".
К сожалению не могу сейчас найти ссылок, может попозже.
Помню, у Катаева было...  
А про именинника в этом значении - у Чуковского(?)

Точно! У Катаева:

> Уж лучше бы я пошел в гимназию, где меня бы как именинника щипали за уши, хотя, в общем-то, я не был именинником, а рожденником, но мои товарищи не вдавались в такие подробности.

http://www.valentinkataev.ru/content/view/2154/479/

PS

> О память сердца, ты сильней
> Рассудка памяти печальной...

Сам удивляюсь, откуда всплывает.

Comment: Я думала, что найдется что-то простое.  А тут такое! Я не знала. Спасибо большое!

Comment: Еще интересно, когда стали празновать дни рождения, а не именины? Советские времена?

Comment: Спасибо за слово! Какое замечательное!

Comment: >Еще интересно, когда стали праздновать дни рождения, а не именины? Советские времена?   
  
Да, конечно. Моя бабушка 1903 г.р. так до конца жизни - а ей Бог отпустил щедро - 96 лет - так и не научилась праздновать ДР. Это по маминой линии, русской.

Answer (score 1):

Чем хорош русский язык, так это возможностью словообразования. Учитывая неформальность праздника искать именно словарный вариант вовсе не обязательно, можно придумать и свои слова.

Днюшник, дЕньщик, днерожденщик.
Днюрожденщик, рождедной.
Сноворожденный, рожденник.
Народившийся, герой.

Comment: Зачем придумывать, если слово давно существует?